# Reading consecutive lines of N digit number into an integer array with each digit in a single array position

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

My file has a 9 digit number in each line and I want to extract each number line-wise and try storing it in a integer array with each digit in each array position.

I tried,

```
while((fgets ( sequence, 9, loose ) != NULL)) {
    if((sequence[0]-'0')==1)
        count(sequence[1]-'0');
    else
        break;
}
```

copying each line to a array called sequence and then converting it to number by `sequence[0]-'0'`, but it doesn't seem to work right; it returns some random number value and loses the file descriptor of my required file.

My file looks something like this
123456789
123456798
123456879
123456897
123456978

i just want first line to be stored as 
sequence[0]=1,sequence[1]=2,...
then the next line text to be over written on sequence[] and so on
until end of file

Comment: `9` : it is not possible to enter only 9-1 characters(8 digit) in fgets. Statement that could not be read is carried over to the next read.

Comment: If i change 9 to 10 then too i am not able to get the next line right it is printing some random number if i do sequence [0]-'0' to convert it to a number

Comment: Newline also includes the character.

Comment: subtracting '0' from only the first char will not turn the string into a number.  However, number = atoi(sequence); will do the job

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I'd suggest that you accept each line of input as a string to a **two** dimensional character array. That way you get each number in its own row with each of the digits in the columns. I can give you the code if you need, but this is pretty straightforward.

Note - You can convert the characters back to integers for further manipulation

EDIT - Added code

```
with open('/root/text.txt') as f:
    number = f.readlines()
number = [x.strip('\n') for x in number]
print number
```

The number printed is a list.

number[0] will give you the first number in your file (123456789)

number[0][0] will give you 1.

int(number[0]) can give you the integer 123456...as opposed to the corresponding string.

Edit 2 -  oops. Just realized I gave you python code :-\

Comment: i have edited my question.i just want to modify my code to read line by line into a integer array digit by digit